# Php, composite pattern, is it bad when child knows about parent?

Tags: php

given this code:

```
class Parent
{
    public function getAdata()
    {
        return array(1,2,3,4);
    }

    public function getChild()
    {
        return new Child ($this);
    }
}

class Child
{
    public function __constructor (Parent $p)
    {
        $p->getAdata();
    }
}
```

they say its bad because `Child` knows about `Parent`. If I rewrite it like this:

```
class Parent
{
    public function getAdata()
    {
        return array(1,2,3,4);
    }

    public function getChild()
    {
        return new Child ($this->getAdata());
    }
}

class Child
{
    public function __constructor ($data)
    {
    }
}
```

its better, but why?

Comment: Who are "they" ? The provided example is too generic to say which is better. It all boils down to what the Child needs to know. If a Child instance will only ever call getData from the parent, then yes it's better to only pass the necessary information.

Comment: you should be using `class Child extends Parent`

Comment: The participants in the composite pattern are component, composite, and leaf, not parent and child

Comment: BTW, it looks like a typo, but... in a *class hierarchy*, a child always needs to know about its parent; it's the parents that should not know about their children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no parent-child relationship here at all. You merely instantiate one class and pass it an instance of another class. There's no problem with that at all, and it doesn't mean those classes are in any sort of relationship.

What *is* bad about the example is that you hardcode `Child` inside of `Parent`. That makes `Child` a hardcoded dependency which cannot be substituted or externally controlled, and hence may cause problems in the future with testing or refactoring code. You should look into dependency injection instead.